# Entity Framework always has pending migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Using Entity Framework 6, with a SQL Server database and code first migrations, I have migrations set up and running "happily", however I'm finding that every time I go to add another migration I get the following error first off:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201602090629398_Initial, 201602090638322_FixSitePageColumns, 201602110313468_RemoveRequiredTemplateId]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration."

If I run `update-database -force` it complains (naturally) that the script fails because of already having been applied.  A strange combination of doign this again and then the `add-migration` works and I can carry on updating to the latest migration.

The list of "pending" migrations also grows with every addded migration over time.

What could cause this "pending" state, when the migration HAS already been applied?  I can confirm that the database has already been updated, the migration exists in `__MigrationHistory`, and the program is running along happily.

**EDIT**

I've also just run `get-migrations` and the following is being returned:

> PM> get-migrations
>   Retrieving migrations that have been applied to the target database.
>   201602110313468_RemoveRequiredTemplateId
>   201602110311536_RemoveRequiredTemplateId
>   201602090638322_FixSitePageColumns
>   201602090629398_Initial

The weird thing here (possibly a red herring) is that `201602110311536_RemoveRequiredTemplateId` is not a migration in my project, I think it may have been one that I created and then deleted, I didn't ever implicitly apply it to the database but it's in the `__MigrationHistory` table.

Comment: Rename your existing database and create an empty one, using the same name. Then, call `update-database`. It should run all migrations. Now, add and apply new migrations and tell me if the problem persists

Comment: Hmm well the last time I did a "force" update and add-migration in a way that made it work, it seems to have fixed it up, so having just done an Add-Migration for a new change (and being prepared to try your suggestion), the issue didn't occur.  I'll try what you'e suggested if it happens again, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because when running Add-Migration it couldn't connect to the database to see what migrations had been applied. I don't have my password stored in the connection string. The fix was to run Add-Migration specifying a complete -ConnectionString and -SqlProvider

```
Add-Migration MigrationName -verbose -ConnectionString "data source=foo.database.windows.net;initial catalog=FOO_DB;user id=admin;password=`"REDACTED`";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the entry for removerequiredtemplateid from the migrations database table and rerun your migration procedure.

Optionally, delete the table altogether, delete all of your migrations, rerun enable-migrations, create a new initial migration and run update-database again (basically, create a fresh start).

Remember to make the required backups beforehand.

Comment: Downvoter : why the downvote?  Please provide an alternative solution, or at least consider posting your reasons for downvoting...